# replace a combination of string only once using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file in which i have many spaces between the columns. I want to replace those spaces with | character but only once.

I tried like this `sed -e "s/ /|/g"` but it relacing evry space with | character.

My file contains

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 
     A     B   C
 D E    F
```

Actually i am fetching data from db2 using script and the output comming like this. I need to put a delimeter between the columns so that i can compare those data later.

I want output like this

```
Col1|Col2|Col3 
A|B|C
D|E|F
```

How can i resolve this. Pls help

Comment: Try `sed -e "s/ {3,}/|/g"` assuming there are 3+ spaces between the columns.

Comment: By what criteria can you tell that there should be a pipe between `D` and `E` but not between `Col` and `1` (for example)? That is really what the question boils down to. I'm guessing that the data fields don't contain single letters in the actual input. We'll need to know more about the actual input to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: it was my mistake. I have editted the question

Comment: You might want to remove leading and trailing whitespace before the replacements with `|` with `sed -e "s/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$//g"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem by using this

`sed -e 's/[ ]\{1,\}/|/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Match a column with space around, ignore if it is the last column.

```
sed -e "s/(?! *(\w+) *$)( *(\w+) *)/$2|/gm"
```

- `( *(\w+) *)` match a word with spaces arround (greedy)
- `?! *(\w+) *$)` Positive lookahead, ignore match that does end the line
- `$2|` replace by the word followed by your delimiter

http://regexr.com/3bvrs

> Actually i am fetching data from db2 using script and the output comming like this.

You might have tabs (`\t`) instead of spaces, its a common separator for *"csv"* exports. Also, if you can modify your script you can specify a delimiter for the export.

Comment: Good suggestion to fix the formatting at the source

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` with `OFS='|'` would be simpler here:

```
awk -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1} 1' file
Col1|Col2|Col3
A|B|C
D|E|F
```

`{$1=$1}` is a way to tell that each record has changed thus it ends up using `OFS` as delimiter for rewriting records.

Answer (score 0):

Replace multispace between data, but not for the header nor trailer space

```
sed -e ':redo' -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^[:blank:]]\)/\1|\2/g;t redo'
```

Due to sed behavior(excluding already taken pattern in a `g` option), 2 pass are needed with this posix compliant version

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^\s+//;s/\s+/|/g' file
```

Remove leading whitespace and replace all other whitespace by `|`